# Switch to complementary colors [black <---> white]

Tags: color, editors

I've decided to work the most I can in dark mode with the applications that I use. So I would like to commpile my LaTeX documents by echanging all the colors to their complementary ones : black --> white, white --> black, and so on.

How do that ? I have two needs.

1. Is there a LaTeX editor with the same feature as evince ? See the following comments.
2. I still need to produce an inverted version for my website. Does it would be better to use freewares directly on PDFs ?

Comment: Your pdf viewers most likely has a *dark mode setting*. No need to introduce LaTeX code that could do mystery stuff two hours to the deadline.

Comment: Evince has "Inverted Colors   Ctrl-I" in the menu. I couldn't find the option in Acrobat Reader 9 but you can change the background http://lifehacker.com/5483656/change-the-background-color-in-adobe-reader-for-eye-friendly-contrast.

Comment: You can [download evince](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince/Downloads) and use it for visualize your documents, it's very nice. It has an option for invert colors: `Ctrl + I` and easy to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks for this tip. I do not why I don't try it before. But my question is still alive. I will update it now.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/197664/7883.  `Emacs` and `vim` both offer many dark themes with syntax highlighting; some are very dark, others more subdued.  Personally, I find dark grey easier on the eyes than white-on-black.  And if my eyes are too tired for a black-on-white pdf, I temporarily set the page color to a pale green, as in eye-ease paper.

Comment: Thanks too. Does the link is a recursive one ?